# Using MPVolumeView, my thumb image shows up underneath the default thumb image using setVolumeThumbImage

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpvolumeview

I am using an MVVolumeView and I am trying to place the default thumb image with my own.

I have a 25 pixel RED square asset that I named VolumeButtonRed.png to test this procedure.

Here is the code where I try to change the thumb image on the slider:

```
[[self mpVolumeViewParentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
MPVolumeView *myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self mpVolumeViewParentView] bounds]];
[[self mpVolumeViewParentView] addSubview:myVolumeView];
[myVolumeView setVolumeThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeButtonRed"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myVolumeView setVolumeThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeButtonRed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

I also added a view and changed it class to MPVolumeView.

I also added these line to my .h file (and linked the outlet):

```
@interface NowPlayingViewController : UIViewController   <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
        MPVolumeView *_mpVolumeViewParentView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MPVolumeView *mpVolumeViewParentView;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, my red square shows up behind the default thumb button and does not replace it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem might lie in code you have not shown us. Maybe you have two volume views or something.

Comment: Other than adding a view and changing its class to MPVolumeView, defining an IBOutlet and _mpVolumeViewParentView in the .h I don't think there is more that I can show (I will add the .h lines to question)

Comment: "adding a view and changing its class to MPVolumeView" That sounds pretty skanky right there. And if you have an outlet, what on earth is your code for? You would wind up with two MPVolumeViews (at least) if you did that.

Comment: Thank-you, your comments let me figure it out!!! Just remove my creation of myVolumeView and use _mpVolumeViewParentView instead.  dah, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you have two volume views, one coming from the storyboard and another created in code.